# Problema con archivo JS en servidor NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, html5, nodejs

Tengo un servidor de NodeJS corriendo en localhost, especificamente el de el paquete NPM llamado http-server, el problema es que estoy ejecutando un script js, y voy probando y recargando, el problema es que tengo que apagar y encender el servidor para que me muestre los nuevos cambios que hice, mi archivo JS es sencillo, solo de practica, es este

```
console.log("Worksssss")

// document.cookie = "nombre=Jose"

var cookies = document.cookie

console.log(cookies)
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema? que no se recarga tu servidor? para eso hay opciones, o puedes hacer un script manual, yo hice uno hace tiempo, pero échale un vistazo a [esto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-hot-loader)

Comment: El problema era chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era el navegador Chrome, probé con Edge y se solucionó el problema

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/112142)

Comment: Yo soy el autor, estoy esperando los dos dias para poder marcar mi respuesta como la respuesta a la pregunta

Comment: Ok, no olvide brindar más detalle a tu respuesta de todas formas, para colaborar así con la comunidad. Buen dia